# GAE Python: Read a JSON file for gitkit

Tags: json, google-app-engine, python-2.7

**RELEVANT CODE**

Attempt 1:

```
directory = os.path.dirname (__file__) 
path = os.path.join (directory, 'json', 'gitkit-server-config.json') 
gitkit_instance = gitkitclient.GitkitClient.FromConfigFile (path)
```

Attempt 2:

```
directory = os.path.dirname (__file__) 
path = os.path.join (directory, 'gitkit-server-config.json') 
gitkit_instance = gitkitclient.GitkitClient.FromConfigFile (path)
```

Getting the following error on dev server as well as production server: 
(Similar error in both attempts)

> INFO     2014-08-29 14:34:21,621 module.py:642] default: "GET
>   /_ah/warmup HTTP/1.1" 500 - ERROR    2014-08-29 09:04:26,540
>   wsgi.py:262]
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line
>   239, in Handle
>
> ```
> handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
> ```
>
> File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line
>   298, in _LoadHandler
>
> ```
> handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line
>   84, in LoadObject
>
> ```
> obj = __import__(path[0])
> ```
>
> File "C:\gaurav\coding\python\myapp\myapp\main_v3.py", line 107, in
>
> ```
> gitkit_instance = gitkitclient.GitkitClient.FromConfigFile (path)
> ```
>
> File "C:\gaurav\coding\python\myapp\myapp\gitkitclient.py", line
>   193, in FromConfigFile
>
> ```
> json_data = simplejson.load(open(config))
> ```
>
> File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\stubs.py",
>   line 248, in **init**
>
> ```
> raise IOError(errno.EACCES, 'file not accessible', filename)
> ```
>
> IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible:
>   'C:\gaurav\coding\python\myapp\myapp\json\gitkit-server-config.json'
>
> INFO     2014-08-29 14:34:26,591 module.py:642] default: "GET
>   /_ah/warmup HTTP/1.1" 500 -

**Relevant snippet of app.yaml:**

```
:: 
handlers: 
# For Google Identity Toolkitv3 Oauth2 
- url: /gitkit-server-config\.json 
  static_files: gitkit-server-config.json 
  upload: gitkit-server-config\.json 
- url: /json 
  mime_type: application/json 
  static_dir: json 
::
```

The file ("gitkit-server-config.json') is copied and kept at both places:

```
C:\\gaurav\\coding\\python\\myapp\\myapp\\gitkit-server-config.json 
C:\\gaurav\\coding\\python\\myapp\\myapp\\json\\gitkit-server-config.json
```

When I put `"http://www.myapp.com/gitkit-server-config.json"` in web browser, the file gets downloaded.

What am I doing wrong? Appreciate your help.

Comment: When a file has been declared static (app.yaml), you cannot read it! You have to create a non static  copy.

Comment: @voscausa Thank you so much. The problem is fixed. I modified the relevant part of app.yaml as shown below: `- url: /json 
  mime_type: application/json 
  static_dir: json 
  application_readable: true` 
Please provide your suggestion as an answer and I would accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not declare a file static in your app.yaml if you have to read this file using Python Files IO. Make a non static copy or change your app.yaml

UPDATE: you can configure '[application_readable](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_Directory_Handlers): true' for a static directory in your app.yaml:

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  application_readable: true
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is fixed. I modified the relevant part of app.yaml as shown below: `- url: /json mime_type: application/json static_dir: json application_readable: true `

Answer (score 3):

All path's should be relative to where your app.yaml lives. So if you directory structure is like

```
| - myapp/
|   | -app.yaml
|   | - json/
|       | - gitkit-server-config.json
```

you can try:

```
path = os.path.join('json', 'gitkit-server-config.json')
gitkit_instance = gitkitclient.GitkitClient.FromConfigFile (path)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I replaced the code with yours but I am getting the following similar error now: `IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: 'json\\gitkit-server-config.json' `